# Porter Stemmer code

Tags: java, nlp, porter-stemmer

I am kinda new to java. I am taking a course in NLP. I wanna know how I can run an input file
on the porter stemmer java code.

Comment: Which porter stemmer java code? there are numbers of ways to implement porter stemmer in java.

Comment: Try processing your input file token by token and running the algorithm for each. Then do something with the stemmed tokens or simply save them to another or same file.

Answer (score 7):

The class below is named PorterAlgo and has various functions for stemming.

```
package com.mycompany.algo;

class NewString {
  public String str;

  NewString() {
     str = "";
  }
}

public class PorterAlgo {

  String Clean( String str ) {
     int last = str.length();

     new Character( str.charAt(0) );
     String temp = "";

     for ( int i=0; i < last; i++ ) {
         if ( Character.isLetterOrDigit( str.charAt(i) ) )
            temp += str.charAt(i);
     }

     return temp;
  } //clean

  boolean hasSuffix( String word, String suffix, NewString stem ) {

     String tmp = "";

     if ( word.length() <= suffix.length() )
        return false;
     if (suffix.length() > 1) 
        if ( word.charAt( word.length()-2 ) != suffix.charAt( suffix.length()-2 ) )
           return false;

     stem.str = "";

     for ( int i=0; i<word.length()-suffix.length(); i++ )
         stem.str += word.charAt( i );
     tmp = stem.str;

     for ( int i=0; i<suffix.length(); i++ )
         tmp += suffix.charAt( i );

     if ( tmp.compareTo( word ) == 0 )
        return true;
     else
        return false;
  }

  boolean vowel( char ch, char prev ) {
     switch ( ch ) {
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': 
  return true;
case 'y': {

  switch ( prev ) {
    case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': 
              return false;

            default: 
              return true;
          }
        }

        default : 
          return false;
     }
  }

  int measure( String stem ) {

    int i=0, count = 0;
    int length = stem.length();

    while ( i < length ) {
       for ( ; i < length ; i++ ) {
           if ( i > 0 ) {
              if ( vowel(stem.charAt(i),stem.charAt(i-1)) )
                 break;
           }
           else {  
              if ( vowel(stem.charAt(i),'a') )
            break; 
       }
   }

   for ( i++ ; i < length ; i++ ) {
       if ( i > 0 ) {
          if ( !vowel(stem.charAt(i),stem.charAt(i-1)) )
              break;
          }
       else {  
          if ( !vowel(stem.charAt(i),'?') )
             break;
       }
   } 
  if ( i < length ) {
     count++;
     i++;
  }
} //while

    return(count);
  }

  boolean containsVowel( String word ) {

     for (int i=0 ; i < word.length(); i++ )
         if ( i > 0 ) {
            if ( vowel(word.charAt(i),word.charAt(i-1)) )
               return true;
         }
         else {  
            if ( vowel(word.charAt(0),'a') )
               return true;
         }

     return false;
  }

  boolean cvc( String str ) {
     int length=str.length();

     if ( length < 3 )
        return false;

     if ( (!vowel(str.charAt(length-1),str.charAt(length-2)) )
        && (str.charAt(length-1) != 'w') && (str.charAt(length-1) != 'x') && (str.charAt(length-1) != 'y')
&& (vowel(str.charAt(length-2),str.charAt(length-3))) ) {

if (length == 3) {
   if (!vowel(str.charAt(0),'?')) 
              return true;
           else
              return false;
        }
        else {
           if (!vowel(str.charAt(length-3),str.charAt(length-4)) ) 
              return true; 
           else
              return false;
        } 
     }   

     return false;
  }

  String step1( String str ) {

     NewString stem = new NewString();

     if ( str.charAt( str.length()-1 ) == 's' ) {
if ( (hasSuffix( str, "sses", stem )) || (hasSuffix( str, "ies", stem)) ){
   String tmp = "";
   for (int i=0; i<str.length()-2; i++)
       tmp += str.charAt(i);
   str = tmp;
}
else {
   if ( ( str.length() == 1 ) && ( str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 's' ) ) {
      str = "";
      return str;
   }
   if ( str.charAt( str.length()-2 ) != 's' ) {
      String tmp = "";
          for (int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++)
              tmp += str.charAt(i);
          str = tmp;
       }
    }  
 }

 if ( hasSuffix( str,"eed",stem ) ) {
   if ( measure( stem.str ) > 0 ) {
      String tmp = "";
          for (int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++)
              tmp += str.charAt( i );
          str = tmp;
       }
 }
 else {  
    if (  (hasSuffix( str,"ed",stem )) || (hasSuffix( str,"ing",stem )) ) { 
   if (containsVowel( stem.str ))  {

      String tmp = "";
      for ( int i = 0; i < stem.str.length(); i++)
          tmp += str.charAt( i );
      str = tmp;
      if ( str.length() == 1 )
         return str;

      if ( ( hasSuffix( str,"at",stem) ) || ( hasSuffix( str,"bl",stem ) ) || ( hasSuffix( str,"iz",stem) ) ) {
         str += "e";

      }
      else {   
         int length = str.length(); 
         if ( (str.charAt(length-1) == str.charAt(length-2)) 
            && (str.charAt(length-1) != 'l') && (str.charAt(length-1) != 's') && (str.charAt(length-1) != 'z') ) {

            tmp = "";
            for (int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++)
                tmp += str.charAt(i);
            str = tmp;
         }
         else
            if ( measure( str ) == 1 ) {
               if ( cvc(str) ) 
                  str += "e";
                }
          }
       }
    }
 }

 if ( hasSuffix(str,"y",stem) ) 
if ( containsVowel( stem.str ) ) {
   String tmp = "";
   for (int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++ )
       tmp += str.charAt(i);
   str = tmp + "i";
        }
     return str;  
  }

  String step2( String str ) {

     String[][] suffixes = { { "ational", "ate" },
                            { "tional",  "tion" },
                            { "enci",    "ence" },
                            { "anci",    "ance" },
                            { "izer",    "ize" },
                            { "iser",    "ize" },
                            { "abli",    "able" },
                            { "alli",    "al" },
                            { "entli",   "ent" },
                            { "eli",     "e" },
                            { "ousli",   "ous" },
                            { "ization", "ize" },
                            { "isation", "ize" },
                            { "ation",   "ate" },
                            { "ator",    "ate" },
                            { "alism",   "al" },
                            { "iveness", "ive" },
                            { "fulness", "ful" },
                            { "ousness", "ous" },
                            { "aliti",   "al" },
                            { "iviti",   "ive" },
                            { "biliti",  "ble" }};
     NewString stem = new NewString();


     for ( int index = 0 ; index < suffixes.length; index++ ) {
         if ( hasSuffix ( str, suffixes[index][0], stem ) ) {
            if ( measure ( stem.str ) > 0 ) {
               str = stem.str + suffixes[index][1];
               return str;
            }
         }
     }

     return str;
  }

  String step3( String str ) {

        String[][] suffixes = { { "icate", "ic" },
                               { "ative", "" },
                               { "alize", "al" },
                               { "alise", "al" },
                               { "iciti", "ic" },
                               { "ical",  "ic" },
                               { "ful",   "" },
                               { "ness",  "" }};
        NewString stem = new NewString();

        for ( int index = 0 ; index<suffixes.length; index++ ) {
            if ( hasSuffix ( str, suffixes[index][0], stem ))
               if ( measure ( stem.str ) > 0 ) {
                  str = stem.str + suffixes[index][1];
                  return str;
               }
        }
        return str;
  }

  String step4( String str ) {

     String[] suffixes = { "al", "ance", "ence", "er", "ic", "able", "ible", "ant", "ement", "ment", "ent", "sion", "tion",
                   "ou", "ism", "ate", "iti", "ous", "ive", "ize", "ise"};

     NewString stem = new NewString();

     for ( int index = 0 ; index<suffixes.length; index++ ) {
         if ( hasSuffix ( str, suffixes[index], stem ) ) {

            if ( measure ( stem.str ) > 1 ) {
               str = stem.str;
               return str;
            }
         }
     }
     return str;
  }

  String step5( String str ) {

     if ( str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'e' ) { 
if ( measure(str) > 1 ) {/* measure(str)==measure(stem) if ends in vowel */
   String tmp = "";
   for ( int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++ ) 
       tmp += str.charAt( i );
   str = tmp;
}
else
   if ( measure(str) == 1 ) {
      String stem = "";
          for ( int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++ ) 
              stem += str.charAt( i );

          if ( !cvc(stem) )
             str = stem;
       }
 }

 if ( str.length() == 1 )
    return str;
 if ( (str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'l') && (str.charAt(str.length()-2) == 'l') && (measure(str) > 1) )
if ( measure(str) > 1 ) {/* measure(str)==measure(stem) if ends in vowel */
   String tmp = "";
           for ( int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++ ) 
               tmp += str.charAt( i );
           str = tmp;
        } 
     return str;
  }

  String stripPrefixes ( String str) {

     String[] prefixes = { "kilo", "micro", "milli", "intra", "ultra", "mega", "nano", "pico", "pseudo"};

 int last = prefixes.length;
 for ( int i=0 ; i<last; i++ ) {
     if ( str.startsWith( prefixes[i] ) ) {
        String temp = "";
            for ( int j=0 ; j< str.length()-prefixes[i].length(); j++ )
                temp += str.charAt( j+prefixes[i].length() );
            return temp;
         }
     }

     return str;
  }


  private String stripSuffixes( String str ) {

     str = step1( str );
     if ( str.length() >= 1 )
        str = step2( str );
     if ( str.length() >= 1 )
        str = step3( str );
     if ( str.length() >= 1 )
        str = step4( str );
     if ( str.length() >= 1 )
        str = step5( str );

     return str; 
  }


  public String stripAffixes( String str ) {

    str = str.toLowerCase();
    str = Clean(str);

    if (( str != "" ) && (str.length() > 2)) {
   str = stripPrefixes(str);

   if (str != "" ) 
      str = stripSuffixes(str);

}   

return str;
} //stripAffixes

} //class
```

Given below is a class PorterCheck.java

```
package com.mycompany.algo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class PorterCheck {
    private static final String DEFAULT_TEST_FILE = "C:/Users/vaibhav/Desktop/rev.txt";
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        PorterAlgo pa = new PorterAlgo();

        //checks for vowels in a given string
        System.out.println(pa.containsVowel("vaibhav"));

        //removes special characters
        System.out.println(pa.Clean("vaibhav's book"));

        //check for a given suffix
        NewString stem = new NewString();
        System.out.println(pa.hasSuffix("corresponding","ing",stem));

        //stemming the words
        ArrayList<String> tok = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] tokens = {"normalize","technical","education"};
        for (String x: tokens){
            tok.add(x);
        }
        System.out.println(completeStem(tok));

        String fileName = ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : DEFAULT_TEST_FILE);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(fileName));
        FileTokenizer fileTokenizer = new FileTokenizer();
        List<String> tokens1 = fileTokenizer.tokenize(fileReader);

        System.out.println("Tokenizing the input file:");
        System.out.print(completeStem(tokens1));
    }

    //method to completely stem the words in an array list
    public static ArrayList<String> completeStem(List<String> tokens1){
        PorterAlgo pa = new PorterAlgo();
        ArrayList<String> arrstr = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String i : tokens1){
            String s1 = pa.step1(i);
            String s2 = pa.step2(s1);
            String s3= pa.step3(s2);
            String s4= pa.step4(s3);
            String s5= pa.step5(s4);
            arrstr.add(s5);
        }
        return arrstr;
    }

    //method to tokenize a file
    public static ArrayList<String> fileTokenizer(){
        StringTokenizer strtoken = new StringTokenizer("this is a book");
        ArrayList<String> filetoken = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(strtoken.hasMoreElements()){
            filetoken.add(strtoken.nextToken());
        }
        return filetoken;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you :D